# How to get principal - user information from a spring boot restApi which has security configured in to a client spring boot app?

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I have two spring boot application. One is Rest and the other one is Spring boot web MVC app which consumes the Rest. The Rest has spring security configured and I want to login/logout from the client app. The client app has nothing but view and controllers to interact with the rest api.

I am using rest template to interact with the api now.

Comment: You can use the token from your REST call and find out the user or principal. Besides this, you are supposed to show your attempt to do what you want to achieve(with code) here.

Answer (score 0):

If the client app is not secured so any other anonymous app may do the same, and this is not security, it's a sieve ...

If you want to create a custom authorization/authentication, you can create own protocol and use tokens/JWT (possibly, OpenID or other global technology) and exchange information between applications.

But there is technology to do it all centrally and reliably - OAuth2, and Spring has it 'from the box' - authorization server, resource server, client. The most advantage - multiple applications (clients), one authorization - you create one user and can authenticate it on any client with the same credentials. You can customize it with JWT, and use any data in the access token and as a consequence get any information about principle/authorization.